# QDbus: register multiple objects on same path

Tags: c++, qt, dbus, qdbus

If I understand, it is possible to use the registerObject method only once on the same path, even if objects have different interfaces in Q_ClassInfo.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is correct.
But if you do want to register multiple objects at the same path, you can do so by declaring those objects (say *childX*, *childY*) as children of an object, say *parentObject* and then calling register object as:

```
registerObject(yourPath, parentObject, QDBusConnection::ExportAdaptors)
```

This will register objects childX and childY at path *yourPath*

Note: *childX* and *childY* must inherit [QDBusAbstractAdaptor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QDBusAbstractAdaptor.html)

Comment: Does it work? I haven't managed to instantiate an object with multiple interfaces for Telepathy API (from specs `Client_Handler.xml` and `Client.xml`, generated bindings like `qdbusxml2cpp -a Client Client.xml` on qt5.5).

Comment: To clarify it a bit:
1. `class ParentClass : public QObject, public QDBusContext` has private members `childX' and 'childY'
2. the `ChildX` and `ChildY` classes are *derived* from the `QDBusAbstractAdaptor` (derived) class
3. when instantiating `ChildX` and `ChildY` use as parent `parentObject` for them
4. register `parentObject` to D-Bus as described in the response above